# No bundle URL present make sure you have running a packager server

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, npm, nodes

i try to compile a projet on reactnative on my new mission

I really try a lot of thing to resolve this error search everywhere but no solution worked for me

i launch

react-native start

from the root project i also tried npm start -- --reset-cache, i tried before to clean and delete cache like this
watchman watch-del-all
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
rm -rf /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*

i'm getting this error on device ios and on simulator like the image show :
No bundle URL present make sure you have running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle

[image]

also i'm noticing that file main.jsbundle is not present anywhere on folder and it's on red on xcode

[image]

same problem with npm start react-native run-ios

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: dumb question, is the local server running?

Comment: in run it with react-native start or with npm start and at the end i'm getting Loading dependency graph, done.

Comment: and when i enter http://localhost:8081/  on navigator i  get React Native packager is running.

Visit documentation

Comment: what happens if you run the project through Xcode? Make sure to close the current server instance first before doing the build through xcode. the main.jsbundle only gets built when you run the build with react-native build. The AppDelegate.m file should be looking at the bundle in memory instead of the main.jsbunlde. If you take a look at the build phases in xcode for your project, there should be a build react native phase in there.